# Backbone View - Render event not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have tried the other suggestions given by StackOverflow before raising this question.

Basically, this issue drives me crazy!! A simple code to render a view which is not firing at the first instance, however when I try to fire it through the Chrome DEV tools it fires!.. Code is given below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="//jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/x-backbone" id="welcome-template">
  <h1>Welcome <%=userName%></h1>
 </script>
 <script>
  var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
     userName: 'Shanun',
     userId: '232221',
     userDept: 'IT'
   }
  });

  var user = new User();
     
  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(){
           this.render();
         },
   render: function(){
    var template = $("#welcome-template").html();
    var compiled = _.template(template, {userName: 'David'});
    this.$el.append(compiled);
   }
  });

  var myView = new MyView ({el: '#app', model: user});
  myView.render();
   </script>
   
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="app"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Can some shed some light please?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not fired? I would assume render is always fired but when script tag is processed for the first time `app` div is not rendered yet so it can't be appended.

Comment: You're spot on!. My Bad!.. Had to enclose my block inside $(document).ready() event, and that resolved the issue.. Thanks for the tip!.